# How to save binary file to SQL by power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, sql

I have got a problem with database. Is there a solution or connector to save a Binary field to SQL database?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: O365 I using in my Tenant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with [BLOB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-crawl-binary-large-objects-blobs-in-sharepoint) in this situation.

If you are using ShP 2010, you can achieve it by following [this guide.](https://www.simego.com/docs/data-sync/howto/sharepoint/import-documents-to-sql)

Some project example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45705277/migrating-attachments-from-sp-to-sql-blob

Comment: but it is a )365. Thease connectors to use blob is Premium. Is there a solution to do this without Premum Connectors ?

Comment: I don't think so.